# Can't get my A3C with LSTM layer using Tensorflow to work

Tags: asynchronous, tensorflow, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I have recently tried to implement my own version of the **Asynchronous Advantage Actor-Critic (A3C)** method for deep reinforcement learning since I couldn't get other A3C implementations found in the web to work properly. The problem is that my version isn't converging either....So, I would really appreciate any help to identify the problem. The code is located in here: https://github.com/MatheusMRFM/A3C-LSTM-with-Tensorflow. I am training the method using the Pong game from the Open AI gym environment. Here's what I did:

- My implementation is heavily based in the following A3C implementations: Arthur Juliani's version, Open AI's A3C and [andreimuntean's version](https://github.com/andreimuntean/a3c). I've chosen these implementations due to their clarity and because everything seemed correct according the the original A3C paper;
- I'm using a network as follows: a set of convolutional layers, a fully connected layer, an LSTM layer, and again, two fully connected layers (one for the policy and the other for the value function). I already tested several other architectures (changing the concolutional layers, removing the first hidden layer, change the output of the hidden and LSTM layers, etc. None of these configurations worked....
- I tried 3 different optimizers: **RMSPropOptimizer**, **AdadeltaOptimizer**, and **AdamOptimizer**. I also tried different learning rates for each one. No luck;
- I already tried several parameters based on the implementations that I looked.

My code always ends up converging to a policy where the paddle always moves up or always moves down (not both). There must be some stupid detail that I missed, but I can't find it. Any help is welcome!

Comment: Stackoverflow didn't allow me to post more links, so here's the link to Arthur Juliani's version: https://medium.com/emergent-future/simple-reinforcement-learning-with-tensorflow-part-8-asynchronous-actor-critic-agents-a3c-c88f72a5e9f2

Comment: I think this question is to broad for us to really help you with what you have given. Perhaps add some plots of how the policy, value and entropy loss evolves over time. And if you skip the LSTM part, and just have a FFNN does it work then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually found what the problem was. And just as I thought, it was only a simple detail that messed everything up: in my code and in all the other codes that I mentioned in my post, the policy loss function uses the softmax log of the policy outputted by the network. In order to avoid Nan results (in case the policy has a 0 associated to at least one action), I added a small value to the policy (in my code, this is done in line 180 from Network.py). It seems that this small value (1e-8) wasn't so small after all, and it was messing with the policy loss function. I ended up using 1e-13 and it then worked. I tested in the VizDoom environment (same map used in Arthur Juliani's version) and it converged within about 6k episodes.

Hope it helps anyone with a similar problem. I will soon update my code in my GitHub account.